# Adjusting the showing time of Shield UI

Tags: javascript, charts, shieldui

I am new to Shield UI Chart and am trying to make my bars show gradually, but it won't work.
    Even the graph won't load when trying with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $("#chart").shieldChart({
applyAnimation: true
  {
    duration: 1500
 },

            axisY: {
                title: {
                    text: "Axis y values"                    
   }
            },
            primaryHeader: {
                text: "Sample statistics"
}, 
dataSeries: [{ seriesType: 'bar',

                collectionAlias: 'Series A',
                data: [129,258,245,458,455]
            }, {
                seriesType: 'bar',
                collectionAlias: 'Series B',
                data: [325,254,145,478,588]
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is merely a synthax error that you have made. You need to set the desired duration, instead of adding true.

Here is the code that works:

```
applyAnimation: {
    duration: 1500
}
```

Comment: I see. There should be only the duration assigned to the property, no enabling the property itself. Thanx!